# Spring Boot logs not showing in minikube

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

I have a Spring Boot app that I deployed to minikube. The app loads fine without pod restarts. Running `kubectl logs` shows valid output:

[image]

However, it only prints the framework logs, it does not print any logs that I add, no matter if I use `Slf4J` logger or `System.out.println`, though on localhost they print fine. Here's my code:

```
package com.mathportal.gateway;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);

    logger.info("After GatewayApplication.run() with logger.info");
    System.out.println("Test...");
}
}
```

Why is that?

---

EDIT:

After running minikube delete and then minikube start, issue was resolved (simply deleting deployments didn’t work). It seems that it was printing logs of the previous version of the app, a version that didn’t include my log statements. But still, this should not happen. Is there any way to solve it without having to delete minikube each time?